# extend MBR disk with ext4 partition to over 2 TB on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, fdisk, parted, mbr

I have a CentOS 7 machine with two disks mounted [ /dev/sda and /dev/sdb ] using ext4.

I need to extend /dev/sdb1 to over 2 TB.

I extended the disk from 2 TB to 2.5 TB (google cloud)

After using fdisk to delete and recreate the partition, after the reboot the resize2fs /dev/sdb1 does not resize the partition to 2.5 TB, since it looks like fdisk has reached the magical 2 TB limit.

Is there a way to extend /dev/sdb1 to lets say 3 TB without losing the data?

Thanks

#### update

as suggested by the fellow serverfault user @mzhaase I tried the *gdisk* with the following steps. The disk was formated with fdisk in total size of 2T

1. stop all services using the /dev/sdb1 partition
2. umount the device
3. Create a backup/snapshot
4. Extend the disk  to 3T
5. install gdisk if not already installed on the instance
6. *gdisk procedure*
   gdisk /dev/sdb
   p  #print and save the GUID
   o  #delete all partitions
   n  #create new partition
   c  #label press ENTER or name if it had it
   x  #enter expert mode
   g  #paste the GUID
   w  #write changes
7. umount /dev/sdb1  #if it gets remounted by gdisk
8. e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1  #check disk
9. resize2fs /dev/sdb1  #resize the partition
10. mount -a  #check if the partitions mount as per fstab
11. reboot  #just to be sure

Comment: I would not use `fdisk` on such large disks. It messes up a lot of things!

Answer (score 6):

There are two major partitioning schemes in use today: **MBR** and **GPT**.

The older, deprecated, and probably still most used one is MBR. However, MBR uses 32 bit to address storage space, using 512 Byte blocks, and 2^32 * 512 Byte are.. 2 TB. So no, you cannot extend an MBR partition over 2 TB. You will need to use GPT for that.

I have never done it myself, but it seems to be possible to convert MBR to GPT without losing data, using [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/). Try it on your own risk.

Comment: that means what the data will have to be destroyed and restored from  a backup, right?

Comment: @nelasx I made another edit. Apparently you can do it without data loss using gdisk. Good luck!

Comment: Taking a backup in any case is prudent if you care about the data. Worst case you do a restore.

Comment: there is a nice document on docs amazon aws explaining how to do it with gdisk. I tried it on a dev instance and it worked out.
[aws docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage_expand_partition.html#part-resize-gdisk)

Comment: @mzhaase  thanks again for your tip on using _gdisk_ it was a life saver.

Comment: @nelasx glad that it worked.